# Weird integrals calculation

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

How to calculate these weird integrals (if it is possible):
$$\int e^{dx}$$ and
$$\int x^{dx}?$$
Thanks

Comment: It just doesn't make sense. ($\lim_{h\rightarrow0}e^h=1\neq0$)

Comment: Do you have a reference for those notations?

Comment: [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shdK9DAiDBE) by Dr Peyam might be able to enlighten you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might extend the definition of an integral by saying that
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(dx)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\bigg(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i\bigg)\cdot g\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$$
However, if you let $g(x)=e^x$, this sum always diverges because $g(1/n)$ does not approach zero as $n\to\infty$. Thus, the integral
$$\int_a^b e^{dx}$$
would diverge if defined in the above sense. However, the integral
$$\int_a^b (e^{dx}-1)=^{?}\space 1$$
could be evaluated using the tentative definition above by noticing that $e^{1/n}-1\sim \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+...$.

For something similar, see my answer to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398920/integral-of-dx2/3398929#3398929) for an explanation of why integrals like 
$$\int_a^b (dx)^2$$
and
$$\int_a^b (dx)^n,\space\space n>1$$
are equal to zero for all values of $a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing Taylor series with $df=f^\prime dx$ gvies $dx^2=0$. Thus $\int e^{dx}=\int(1+dx)$ makes no sense; nor does $\int x^{dx}=\int\exp(dx\ln x)=\int(1+dx\ln x)$. But$$\int\left(e^{dx}-1\right)=\int dx=x+C,\,\int(x^{dx}-1)=x\ln x-x+C.$$